# /post/how-to-write-a-pattern-to-accept-this-kind_of_url (In Django)

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm trying to achieve a product URL as shown below:

> base_url/product/**this-is-sample-of-product-1**

URL can have a combination of the hyphen, underscore, a-zA-Z,0-9 (Similar to the url of posts as in wordpress)

Please help, How to achieve this in urls.py - Django.

I have tried this code in my urls.py but it is not working.

```
url(r'^product/([-\w]+)/$', views.SingleProduct.hello, name='hello' ),
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried so far, or links to any documentation you've looked at?

Comment: What have you tried? Django `url` matching rules are just plain regular expressions. You should be able to match those characters quickly and easily after reading a Python regex tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, Just updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the slug field in model.

> urls.py

```
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.SingleProduct.hello, name="hello"),
```

> views.py

```
  class SingleProduct(APIView):
    def hello( request, slug ):
      return HttpResponse('It works')
```